# jQuery clone() input value function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a clone function to clone a selection of elements. I have managed to get the basics of the clone function working. [CLICK HERE](http://iamnatesmithen.com/store/app/)
I have a bug in this function. When the user types text into the input field, it clones the last inputted text and changes the text value for all cloned items.

```
$('.add-item').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('input').val();
  if ($('#items-field').val()) {
    $('.list-items p').text(value)
    $('.list-items:first').clone().appendTo("#items").addClass('isVisible');
    $('input').val('');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Does anyone know how this problem can be resolved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clear the value of inputs after you `clone()`. You can use the `find()` method to get all the inputs inside the cloned item.

```
var c = $('.list-items:first').clone();
c.find("input").val("");  // find all inputs and clear
c.appendTo("#items").addClass('isVisible');
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/leqizo/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working jsbin sample

Also, In your code, you are reading the input value and setting it to all the `p` tags's text. You should be setting it only to the p tag of the cloned div.

```
$(function(){

  $('.add-item').on('click', function(e) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var value = $('#items-field').val();
     if (value!="") {

       var c = $('.list-items:first').clone();
       c.find("input").val("");  // find all inputs and clear
       c.appendTo("#items").addClass('isVisible');

       c.find("p").text(value);

     }
  });

})
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/nefeje/edit?html,js,output) is a working sample of the complete solution

Comment: Not sure that works the way i described in my question, based off your example, it clones the items but if you were to type a name into the text field then press clone it doesn't clone that individual name. for example try the following. type into the text field tom > press clone steve > press clone etc

Comment: See my updated answer. That has a working sample as well.